# Decompression gzip in OData

Tags: c#, wcf, gzip, wcf-data-services, compression

I need help in decompressing **gzip WCF DataService Responses**, because I configured **IIS** to compress responses. I'm sending in header of requests `Accept-Encoding gzip`, deflate, but now I can't find any help how I can get selected entity from DB (for example Clients).

**Here is my code:**

```
DbServiceReference.MainDBEntities proxy;
string message;

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        proxy = new MainDBEntities(new Uri("http://localhost/DotConnectTest/MainDbDataServices.svc/"));


        proxy.BuildingRequest += proxy_BuildingRequest;
        proxy.ReceivingResponse += proxy_ReceivingResponse;


        txtBox.Text = proxy.Clients.FirstOrDefault().Name;
    }


    void proxy_ReceivingResponse(object sender, System.Data.Services.Client.ReceivingResponseEventArgs e)
    {   
        Stream stream = new GZipStream(e.ResponseMessage.GetStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress);
        message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ReadFully(stream)); // here I can Encode Response to string contains Client object in xml                         
    }

    public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    void proxy_BuildingRequest(object sender, System.Data.Services.Client.BuildingRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        KeyValuePair<string, string> header = new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        if (!e.Headers.Contains(header))
            e.Headers.Add(header);      
    }
```

Now I get an error:

> Unable to translate bytes [8B] at index 1 from the specified code page to Unicode.

in this part of code:

```
txtBox.Text = proxy.Clients.FirstOrDefault().Name;
```

I find tutorial where I saw how to use **ReadingResponse** event, but I think in new version of **Data Service ReadingResponse** event don't exist. I have only ReceivingResponse event, but there I can't override content of received message.

Have any ideas how resolve this problem? How I can get Client name and set it to textBox.Text property?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I know how resolve my problem finally!

I used **sendingRequest2** :

```
void proxy_SendingRequest2(object sender, System.Data.Services.Client.SendingRequest2EventArgs e)
    {
        var Request = ((HttpWebRequestMessage)e.RequestMessage).HttpWebRequest;

        Request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    }
```

Comment: But it isn't working in Portable Class Library...
Anybody know how make decopression in PCL?